# how to add key and a value to a json with same existing Key using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json variable like this

```
var jsondata={"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}
```

I want to push another object with same existing key, and i want that my variable will be like this

```
var jsondata={"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2", "key1":"val3"}
```

I tried `jsondata["key1"] = "val3"`, but it didn't return the wanted result

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can not use same field names. Object keys must be unique

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible in javascript as all keys must be unique. You probably want to use a different data structure. What is the problem you are trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Keys can't be duplicated.

Comment: @RohanOrton, did you mean "Fortunately"?

Comment: define your "another object" how it looklike

Comment: I have edit my post, with the good example

Answer (score 0):

you cannot, as it is a map.
but you could create this json :

```
var jsondata={"Name":["Jhon","James"], "Age":40}
```

Comment: `a map`, no in js it is called as an object.

Comment: I beg to differ but in this scenario I doubt John and James are the names of the same person. I suppose what he really needs is an array of person objects

Comment: `this json` the thing that you have displayed is an object not a JSON.

Comment: In resume, i want many same keys , with different values, not important if the object is referenced to person or other types

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Although this is a javascript object, his object is valid JSON. You don't use JSON directly from javascript, you'd parse it into a javascript object (JAVASCRIPT OBJECT NOTATION) - so whilst it's not a JSON string, his object is valid JSON.

Comment: What i really need, is to have the json with some same keys, because i will pass it to script that generate an excel file

Answer (score -1):

You can't use the same key in an object. Your question suggests that the logic behind your data structure is wrong.

An alternative:

Use a different field name, i've used "_Name" below, but perhaps "Second_Name" would be more appropriate. Unsure what your json data is modelling.

```
var jsondata={"Name":"Jhon", "Age":40, "_Name":"James"};
```

Or perhaps it makes sense to store an array of people, is that what you're trying to achieve? i.e. you have two people, with the names "Jhon" and "James"?

```
var jsondata={

     "people": [

          {"Name":"Jhon", "Age":40},
          {"Name":"James"}
    ]
};
```

Comment: Why has this received 4 downvotes? Two valid solutions to a very vague question here. I edited it to add a second solution which implements an array of people but the first is just as valid... No comments either to suggest why the downvotes.

Comment: Thank you for details, it's an example what i  mentioned, i want to store data in my object, with the same same key like this : var jsondata={"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2", "key3":"val3"};

Comment: @user2285831 That is quite different to what you have asked in the original question?

Comment: what i asked is that i have this object :  var jsondata={"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"} and i want to add to it other data so it will be like this : jsondata={"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2", "key3":"val3"};

Comment: I have edit my post, with the good example